# How can I undo a local file replace mistake, I was using git but hadn't staged it before it was gone

Tags: git, ubuntu, atom-editor

I've made a booboo! I've been coding up a file for 1 hr, which I was about to add to staging but that file got replaced. And deleted. Is there anyway back in the past where I can get that file back?

I'm using Ubuntu, with git and Atom is my text editor.

What do I do? Code it up again? :-(

Comment: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/446277/how-to-recover-a-file-overwritten-with-another-in-linux)

Comment: Unfortunately, if you haven't even called `git add` before, `git` can't help you. As @Sheharyar suggests, you may look at the tools to dig in your filesystem, but the 1hr delay will be quickly reached ...